# Loop through all Unicode characters

Tags: c#, unicode

In C# is it possible to loop through every single character defined by the Unicode standard?
Does that even make sense?

Comment: I don't want just the printable characters, I want every character in Unicode, whether printable or not.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, and it's not terribly hard, since unicode characters are just integers. You'll need a database, though, since there's no algorithmic way of knowing which values are assigned. There are a couple of known *forbidden* values (e.g. the last two in every plane), but there are many other "holes".

Comment: Can't you just loop from 0 to Max or something?

Comment: @SachinKainth What is the reason that you are doing this? Looping through all of the Unicode characters is going to be some very performance-heavy and memory-heavy code.

Comment: For a unit test.  I want to test a particular method and pass each character in turn into that method.  Plus it sounds fun :)

Comment: That's a pretty questionable duplicate, a *char* is not a Unicode codepoint.  If this is intended for testing then you want to test the oddballs, the ones that require two chars to map the the supplementary planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enumerate all the assigned values in [the Unicode character database](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt). Exclude everything in angled brackets, I suppose.